# SQL - Convert a series of updated dates into rows of start and end dates

Tags: sql, date, version, transpose

I have a kind of attribute record table with a list of customers, an attribute, and a date. This table updates once a month with the current attribute values for all the customers.

```
id     attr_val     date
1      red          2012-01-01
1      red          2012-02-01
1      blue         2012-03-01
2      green        2012-01-01
2      green        2012-02-01
2      green        2012-03-01
```

I would like to recast or transpose this table so that it lists a start and end date for each attribute value. That way I can take an arbitrary date and do `date between start_dt and end_dt` to get the value on that date.

```
id     attr_val     start_dt       end_dt
1      red          2012-01-01     2012-02-28
1      blue         2012-03-01     NULL
2      green        2012-01-01     NULL
```

Is this possible with a single SQL command, or would I need to run some kind of more complex script? Target environment is Teradata but I think the solution is platform independent...

Comment: The `end_dt` seems to have no correlation with your example data.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want

```
SELECT id, attr_val, min(date) as start_dt, max(date) as end_dt
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id, attr_val
```

or this:

```
SELECT id, attr_val, min(date) as start_dt,CASE WHEN max(date) > min(date) THEN max(date) ELSE null END as end_dt
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id, attr_val
```

Comment: The min(date), max(date) solution would not work when attributes change from one value to another and back again. The records will show attribute date ranges as overlapping... Wish it was that easy...

Comment: @user548084 - err... ok then how do you keep the "sessions" distinct?

Answer (score 1):

A good solution for this is a correlated subquery:

```
select id, attr_val, min(date) as start_date, end_date
from (select t.*,
             (select min(date) - 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.date > t.date and t2.attr_val <> t.attr_val
             ) as end_date
      from t
     ) t
group by id, attr_val, end_date
```

This calculates the next date where the attribute is different for a given id and attribute value.  One less than this date is the end date.  When the attribute for a given id has the same value on successive rows, they all get the same end_date (even if NULL).  The query then uses this end date for grouping them together.

Comment: Ah, that's where the `end_dt` comes from.